# JSON POST 400 error / mysql datetime format

Tags: mysql, json

Need help with the following. I am getting 400() error when doing JSON POST to mysql. 
The output of JSON object is:

```
{
checkOutDatetime:"2017年6月25日 AM 07:00:00"

id:"2"

licenseNum:"ABC-1234"

returnDatetime:"2017年6月25日 下午 05:00:00"
}
```

When I use postman, I get json data from mysql as follow:

```
{
    "id": 2,

    "licenseNum": "ABC-1234",

    "checkOutDatetime": 1498345200000,

    "returnDatetime": 1498381200000
}
```

Couple of things:

1. The order of items are not the same.  This shouldn't be a problem.
   right? The datetime format seems to be different.
2. How do I convertthe object's datetime format into MySql's datetime
   format?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi all, it looks like
1- the order of items does not matter.
2- I was able to convert the datetime to UNIX format using the following
moment($("#checkOutDatetime").val()).unix()*1000

Comment: But.... now I have another issue.
If I use moment.js with locale other then 'en', the above conversion won't work.
So.... any idea how to make conversion work in other locale?